# Administrator Console Guide for JBOSS AS 6

Tags: jboss

Does anyone able to share documentation guide for JBOSS AS 6?
Currently i only able to found the link below and it is broken link.
Please share to me if you have a copy of documentation for JBOSS AS 6.
https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossApplicationServerOfficialDocumentationPage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need this one [here](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/6/Admin_Console_Guide/en-US/html/): Administration Console User Guide for JBoss Application Server 6.

And maybe you can also take a look [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6/). It can help you too (it's not the same, but as I said, it may help).

Comment: this is exactly what i need. Thanks a lot for the help. :)